# Multiplication with the derivative of the dirac delta

Tags: calculus, signal-processing, dirac-delta

I have a function $x(t)$ that I'm multiplying with $\frac{d}{dt}\delta(t-kT)$
I know the property that $\frac{d}{dt}\delta(t-kT) = -\frac{\delta(t-kT)}{t-kT}$, and if I use that: $x(t)\frac{\delta(t-kT)}{kT-t} = x(kT)\frac{\delta(t-kT)}{kT-t}$

I'm not sure what this function looks like when $t=kT$, since the denominator is infinite, and $\delta(t-kT)$ is also of infinite height at $t=kT$ Is it just undefined, or does the delta function have some other property that I'm missing that makes it a defined function of some sort.

PS: I'm tagging this as signal processing since I encountered the function while doing signal processing stuff.

Comment: It doesn't look like anything since it is undefined. Also, $x(t) \delta (t - y) \neq x(t-y) \delta(t-y)$. The derivative of the delta function doesn't exist in the usual sense, rather only in the distributional, but I assume you are already aware of that.

Comment: I was told that $x(t)\delta(t-t_0) = x(t_0)\delta(t-t_0)$, is that not right?

Comment: That relation is right, but that's not what's in your post.

Comment: I don't remember the identity $\delta^\prime(t-a) = -{\delta(t-a)\over t-a}$. (Granted, it's been a while.) If I integrate both sides against a test function $f(t)$, I obtain $-f^\prime(a) = -{f(a)\over t-a}$, which is not an identity....

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85, Oops sorry typo! Will correct it now!

Comment: @JasonZimba, I found it on Wikipedia. I think it only holds for the delta function (and not in general)

Comment: Could you provide the Wikipedia link?

Comment: @JasonZimba, it is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Distributional_derivatives)

Comment: OK thanks for the link. I will move my thoughts down to the answer section so I can see what I'm typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, but I'm answering here so I can see what I'm TeX'ing.

I'm concerned that you are pursuing an incorrect approach. The identity $$\delta^\prime(t-kT) = -{\delta(t-kT)\over t-kT}$$ is false. To see this, integrate both sides of the identity against $e^{-t^2}$. The left-hand side yields
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\delta^\prime(t-kT)\, e^{-t^2}\,dt} =2kTe^{-(kT)^2}$$
while the right-hand side yields
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{{\delta(t-kT)\over t-kT}\, e^{-t^2}\,dt} ={\rm ??}$$

Consulting the link you provided, I suspect you got $\delta^\prime(t-kT) = -{\delta(t-kT)\over t-kT}$ by dividing both sides by $x$ in the true identity $$x\delta^\prime(x) = -\delta(x)\,.$$
But that leads to trouble here.

Consider that if we could do such operations freely with delta functions, then from the true identity $x\delta(x) = 0$ we could derive the false identity $\delta(x) = 0$ by dividing both sides by $x$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed that, must've just gotten carried away by things..